# php directory content list above root

Tags: php

how do i use php to access the directory above my site root, i need to specifically go up one directory and show contents to the user so they can pick from a couple different directories on the same level as public_html, navigate into them, and when clicking on a file serve it up?  server is unix/apache

zips
anims
public_html
Thank you ahead.

David

Answer (score 1):

i found that if they know the file name it can be served to them by this... named image.php
then image.php?file=imagename.jpg

Thank you!

```
<?php 

$file = $_GET['file']; 
$fileDir = '/path/to/files/'; 

if (file_exists($fileDir . $file)) 
{ 
// Note: You should probably do some more checks 
// on the filetype, size, etc. 
$contents = file_get_contents($fileDir . $file); 

// Note: You should probably implement some kind 
// of check on filetype 
header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 

echo $contents; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You go up one directory using the .. link.  Example:

```
<?php include("../foo.bar"); ?>
```

Note that if you're on shared hosting, there's a good chance that the server won't let you do this.

Comment: No problem, David.  Your posted solution looks pretty good, but you could potentially have some issues with users using your script to pull out and read filesystem data like your apache confs.  Something like "if (strpos($_GET['file'],'/')=0 || strpos($_GET['file'],'..')){ will stop users grabbing from parent directories or root.

Comment: By the by, it's customary to vote up answers that are useful to you.  You can also accept the answer by clicking the checkmark.